# domain serves content from subdomain on another website

Tags: php, web, redirect

I have several sub-domains on 1 website

```
http://sub1.mysite.com
http://sub2.mysite.com
http://sub3.mysite.com
```

I've also registered equivalent domains for each of these sub-domains at

```
sub1.com
sub2.com
sub3.com
```

How can I set it so that when someone types the `sub1.com` domain, they see the content from `http://sub1.mysite.com` but still see `sub1.com` as the URL. So the content is really served from `http://sub1.mysite.com` without the visitors knowing that.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of multi-layered.

Firstly, you need to setup a **CNAME** record for **sub1.com** to point to **sub1.domain.com**. This is done via whoever is hosting the DNS for sub1.com. You should more than likely have a control panel at either your hosting company or your domain name registrar to add this.

All this does however is tell clients that your website sub1.com lives at a certain IP address (i.e. in the case of a CNAME, it says, look up the IP of sub1.domain.com and sub1.com lives at the same location.)

Secondly, you need to tell your webserver that sub1.com and sub1.domain.com are the same site.

For Apache, you probably already have a **`<VirtualHost>`** setup, so you would add in a **ServerAlias** directive to tell Apache that the VirtualHost also serves sub1.com as well as sub1.domain.com

*...* signifies that you have your own configuration directives in here already.

```
<VirtualHost ...>
    ServerName sub1.domain.com
    ServerAlias sub1.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Thirdly and lastly, you need to make sure that your site doesn't redirect or reference sub1.domain.com within the code (i.e. Header redirects through PHP, meta tag refreshes, or `a href` links within the HTML to redirect the user outside of the current domain).

Links should have absolute paths without the domain, e.g. 1 not 2

**1.**

```
<a href="/blah.html">Blah</a>
```

**2.**

```
<a href="http://sub1.domain.com/blah.html">Blah</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the domains point to the same server of the subdomains, and using your hosting control panel set the domains as aliases to the subdomain.

p.s. asking those questions on https://serverfault.com/ gives you much better feedback, since that is the place to ask such questions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a CNAME entry to your DNS zone. However you might need to adjust some login in your code if its dependent on requested host, cause your scripts will not see sub1.mysite.com but sub1.com, so adjust them accordingly to handle both cases.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you want a "Frame Redirect":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Frame_redirects

Comment: This won't work for embedded images/css/js..

Comment: Ugh, there are soooooo many better ways of doing this

Comment: Fast, good, cheap. Pick two.